# Correct schema for multiple randomly ordered elements

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, xsd

I'm creating a schema from an xml document that contains multiple elements of a few types but in a random order that needs to be maintained once serialized and then deserialized (I'm programming in VB.NET but a C# answer is fine so I haven't specified the language).

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<sample:ABC>
   <sample:DEF></sample:DEF>
   <sample:XYZ></sample:XYZ>
   <sample:DEF></sample:DEF>
   <sample:PNQ></sample:PNQ>
   <sample:DEF></sample:DEF>
   <sample:DEF></sample:DEF>
</sample:ABC>
```

So far I have this schema which was produced by xsd.exe:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="ABC">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="DEF" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="XYZ" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="PNQ" minOccurs="0" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

However this doesn't match all the possible ways the xml may come in and obviously I've simplified the xml and schema massively, and shown only one sample to make it easier to demonstrate the problem.

I've seen a suggestion to use the [`all`](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_all.asp) element but that only allows for one of each child. I've also tried adding duplicate child elements (e.g. two DEF elements) but that creates an 'ambiguous' schema. 
I've also tried using a sequence of choice elements but the code generated from the schema then has to use Objects and so is not type safe. I think it might be possible to use inheritance to solve this but my schema skills are not up to it.

The question is: are there any schema elements can be used to get a correct match to the xml? If not can I at least create a schema that can be used to check the xml for validity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match abitrary sequences of `DEF`, `XYZ` and `PNQ` elements in any order and any number you can use:

```
<xs:schema 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns="test" 
  targetNamespace="test" 
  elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="ABC">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="DEF" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="XYZ" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="PNQ" minOccurs="0" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The only difference with your schema is the addition of `maxOccurs="unbounded"` for `xs:sequence`

Note though that an XML like this cannot be de-serialized using the standard de-serialization in a .NET class - elements with the same name are de-serialized to list or arrays, and must be consecutive.

You can handle such a case using custom de-serialization - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly).

Comment: That's a shame about the deserialization but it was what I was suspecting. It's not possible to get everything in one solution.

Comment: @ClaraOnager: actually, I just remembred about `IXmlSerializable` - see expanded answer

Comment: I understand **why** this works now thanks to seeing this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469378/any-difference-when-you-use-min-maxoccurs-at-sequence-rather-than-element-level
When you use maxoccurs unbounded at the sequence level you can repeat the set (aka sequence) of elements over and over again. Combined with minoccurs zero this allows for exactly what I need